# Best way to zero out sparsematrix coefficients in Eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen

The SparseMatrix type in the Eigen C++ library, let's say

```
SparseMatrix<double, RowMajor> A;
```

seems to be missing a coeffFind(i,j) method with InnerIterator or double* as return type. So to ensure that A has no non-zero coefficient at position (i,j), I can either do

```
A.coeffRef(i,j) = 0.0;  // Adds an entry with zero value!
```

or

```
if (A.coeff(i,j) != 0.0) {
  A.coeffRef(i,j) = 0.0;  // Double look-up cost!
}
```

or write my own look-up method which would be duplicating the binary search used internally in Eigen. What should I do?

Comment: You're right, I followed `coeffRef` by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with write your own if performance is critical (important enough). Otherwise, based on only the complexity:

1. a lookup is O(log(nnz))
2. an insertion (O(1) or O(nnz) depending on where it is inserted - also reserves more memory if the matrix is compressed)

Thus, the costs are O(nnz) always for the second option or O(log(nnz)) for the first if there is no element. If there is an element, the cost is going to be twice O(log(nnz)) in any case so your saving O(log(nnz)) is not going to be significant relative to the insertion in the second method. If it really is critical, then write your own.

Comment: What execution path leads to A.coeff(i,j) inserting zeroes? I see coeff(...) in Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseMatrix.h calling atInRange(...) from Eigen/src/SparseCore/CompressedStorage.h and returning Scalar(0.0) if not found..

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I followed coeffRef.